# Where should I put the catch in my try/catch?

Tags: java, try-catch

I want the program to end when the user puts in letters and words when they don't use numbers.

```
try {
      // The user is asked to enter a starting and ending number
      System.out.print("\n");
      System.out.println("\nNow type a starting number in digit form:");
      int num1 = myObj.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Now give an ending number:");
      int num2 = myObj.nextInt();
      
      // If the first number is less than the second number this block will be used
         if (num1 < num2) {
            for (;num1 < num2; num1++) {
               System.out.print(num1 + " ");
            }
         }
      
      // If the first number is more than the second number this block will be used
         else {
            for (;num1 > num2; num2++) {
               System.out.print(num2 + " ");
            }
         }
      }
      /*catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
            System.out.println("You need to enter a number like 12.34. Try again.");
         }*/
      // The user will enter a phrase here
      myObj.nextLine();
      System.out.println("\n");
      System.out.println("Write a phrase you want.");
      phrase = myObj.nextLine();
      
      // The user will enter how many times the phrase should be printed
      System.out.println("How many times would you like this printed?");
      int rep = myObj.nextInt();
      for (int i = 0; i < rep; i++)
         System.out.println(phrase);
      
      catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
            System.out.println("You need to enter a number like 12.34. Try again.");
         }
```

The first catch in this is commented out for the moment and it works, but the code continues on to the second function when I don't want it to. The second catch gives me two errors. One at the try saying it doesn't have a catch and at the catch at the bottom saying it doesn't have a try. The second catch isn't commented out. The second function after this does something else and it doesn't need a try/catch.

I'm not sure what else to put to make the catch end the program and not continue to the second function.

Comment: `catch (SomeException e) { System.exit(-1); }`